# Why can questions that use existing tags be considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-questions

Sorry for the originally poorly-worded question. I tried to improve it.

---

I asked my [first question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128428/how-much-memory-is-needed-to-run-a-minecraft-server-in-1-6-2) the other day on Gaming.SE regarding system requirements for a Minecraft Server.  I conveniently found two tags: [system-requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-requirements) and [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server). This, I thought, gave me strong assurance that my question was appropriate for the forum.

And lo' and behold 2 days later, it's been deemed off topic.

So my question: Is it possible for a question to perfectly fit established tags and still be off topic?

And my second question: since this could apply to ANY SE site, is my meta question also off-topic? :)

Comment: The existence of a tag in no way deems everything related to that tag on topic.

Answer (score 10):

> *Is it possible for a question to perfectly fit established tags and still be off topic?*

Yes they can. Consider *"What are the system requirements to run Photoshop?"*. This may suit the [system-requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-requirements) tag, but Photoshop is off-topic on Arqade as it is not a video game or video-game-related software.

Questions can be closed no matter how well tagged they are, sorry. :-).